# SiriKit Extension not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios10, sirikit

I enabled Siri in Capabilities in Xcode, I also added the NSSiriUsageDescription to my parent app plist file and ask for the Siri permission in my first controller.

But if I start my SiriKit extension and try to ask Siri to my "INRequestRideIntent" I configured in my SiriKit Extension plist in "IntentsSupported", she told me always that the app I required has no siri support, but I added the Siri support to the app.

I am really desperate and I don't know what I am doing wrong, can you please give me an advice?

Currently what I've done looks like this:

Extension .plist-file:

[image: Extension .plist-file]

Extension project structure:

[image: Extension project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with SiriKit was, that the correct target was missing. So I have to add the target for Siri. But Siri has also a problem with my app name. If I choose another app name the SiriKit extension starts as expected. It is a bug and I reported it after talking to the technical support.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the AppIntentVocabulay.plist to your Siri Extention. That is where you define your commands like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I added this file to my project and now it propose my app when I say sth like "Call me a taxi". When I proceed with my app, everything is working fine. When I ask Siri for help it also propose my app with an example phrase. But the curios think is, when I say "Call me an MyAppTaxi", Siri say that it is not possible to open "MyAppTaxi".

Comment: When I setup my device to english and say "Call me an MyAppTaxi", I can book me a ride with my app. But if I do this in german it does not work. I also localize the AppIntentVocabulay.plist but this does not help. I also have english and german as app language. I am not sure, that sirikit is a little bit buggy at the moment

Comment: Siri can only speak one language at a time. When your phone is set up for english it will only understand english, and when it is set up for German, it will only respond to german commands.

Comment: By the way, if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct and upvote it. Then it will be easier for others with the same problem to find a helpful answer :)

Comment: I cannot vote up an question, because I have no permission to do this, because of the current state of the account. Upvotes are only count internally. I setup my device in english and get an correct answer. But when I setup my device in german, I don't get the expected answer for my app. That's the reason I am wondering about the problem.

Comment: ok, but as you were able to ask the question, you should be able to accept an answer :) About the german language problem, I'm not sure how to help you. I have set up my own Siri-kit app with English and Norwegian. Norwegian works, but I have actually not tested the english localization. As I understand it, localizing the appintentvocabulary.plist should be enough though.

Comment: This was a an advice how with the result, that the app appears in the sirikit help section, but it doesn't provide the effect that I can speak a phrase for example "Pick me up with MyAppTaxi" and the app reacts like expected. I found out, that all apps on my phone that are using sirikit on german aren't currently working, so I think that apple currently has a bug here.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you have added below Autherizaion block in your ViewController or not.

```
[INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:^(INSiriAuthorizationStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case INSiriAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"Authorized");
                break;
            case INSiriAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"Denied");
                break;
            case INSiriAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"NotDetermined");
                break;
            case INSiriAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"Restricted");
                break;
        }
    }];
```

If this block is already added then fine.
Next thing is Whatever your app name, it should be in your Vocabulary file with phrases.
i.e. "Book a taxi in MyAppTaxi". This kind of perfect UK English phrases are acceptable in Siri.